# Display out of stock for components of grouped products

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory, grouped-products

How can I display "out of stock" for individual components of grouped products, when any of the  individual component (simple product) goes out of stock?  As it is now it displays the quantity boxes, even if the simple product is out of stock!

Is there an admin setting for this?

While searching, I found [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105289/grouped-products-is-it-possible-to-show-out-of-stock-status-individually). Is this the way to do it?  Or is there a better method.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**OK, I figured out the solution.** When I re-indexed, it started displaying "out of stock".